# Simple LinkButton Postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

This has got to be the simplest question ever. Im trying to use a link button with the "postbackurl" to post a value to another page. It works with a button, but it is blank with a linkbutton. I dont want to use querystring. Any ideas?

default.aspx:

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton" postbackurl="~/2.aspx" Text="ThisIsATest" runat="server">ThisIsATest</asp:LinkButton>
```

2.aspx:

```
    Dim test = Request.Form("LinkButton")

    Response.Write(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```
var text = ((LinkButton)PreviousPage.FindControl("LinkButton")).Text;
```

Comment: Still nothing. Its in a gridview (gridview1) thats in a contentplaceholder(content1), does that matter? Ive done research but its only confused me further.

Comment: You will need to go further than just looking in the GridView for the LinkButton. You also need to reference the correct row that the LinkButton is in.

Comment: Exactly you references your grid and row, in the id

Comment: How do i reference the grid and row dynamically when i click the link?

Comment: you have nested UniqueId , UniqueID uses colon as separator from parent control to child control,

Answer (score 0):

Use PreviousPage.FindControl to get the control reference

```
Dim lb As LinkButton = DirectCast(PreviousPage.FindControl("LinkButton"), LinkButton)

If lb IsNot Nothing Then
     Response.Write(test.ID) ' display linkbutton ID
     Response.Write(test.Text) ' display linkbutton Text
End If
```

Comment: Its in a gridview (gridview1) thats in a contentplaceholder(content1), does that matter?

Comment: yes that matters, check this as `PreviousPage.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderID$GridViewID$LinkButton"), LinkButton)`

Comment: You can use FindControl to dynamically get your id's for the ContentPlaceHolder and GridView.
PreviousPage.FindControl("Content1").FindControl("GridView1").FindControl("LinkButton1") could be used, but if any of the FindControl calls returna null/nothing, the code will blow up

Comment: @Scott sorry scott that does not matter if we use PreviousPage.FindControl.

Comment: I keep getting a NullReferenceException even though none of my columns/rows are null. Tried pretty much everything on this page so far so this is directed at all.

Comment: @Scott yeah, The ID of control changes if control is inside a master page.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how I go about getting this dynamic control name? I see it increments by one. So close, almost there. :)

Comment: @Scott see this link, may be helpful for you http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/05/14/using-findcontrol-and-previouspage-with-master-pages.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    Response.Redirect("2.aspx?id=" + somestring)
End Sub
```

Comment: "I dont want to use querystring."